# How get firebase auth uid if I'm using facebook for authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Facebook authentication is successful but **I want to know how to get firebase auth.uid**.
This is my android app firestore facebook login code.

Login.Activity :

```
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        ImageView ivLoginScreenImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLoginScreenImage);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.image_swing)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(ivLoginScreenImage);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    
      loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    
    
    
    
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Success " + loginResult.toString());
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
    
    
    
    
                ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                        this.stopTracking();
                        Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);
                        Log.d(TAG,"Setting current profile " + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getFirstName());
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                        User user = User.fromJSON(object);
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Returning logged user info " + user.getName() + " " + " " + user.getEmail());
                                        //On Successful login
                                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                                        returnIntent.putExtra("loggedUser", user);
                                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email, gender, age_range, link");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }
                };
                profileTracker.startTracking();
            }
    
    
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled");
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.toString());
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
    
    
        });
    }
    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    
    
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    
    
                            if (user != null) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "email" + user.getEmail());
                            }
    
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
    
                        }
    
    
                    }
                });
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

I have tried this code and i called the **userr** in a code which will update to firestore. The signin successful but this userr is null so i get below error

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     FirebaseUser userr = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid;
```

Error as **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference**

Guys help needed please.

Comment: Are you seeing the email getting logged with this line: `Log.i(TAG, "email" + user.getEmail())` ?

Comment: `mAuth.getCurrentUser` is returning null because no user is signed in at the time you called it.  Read: [Why is my currentUser == null in Firebase Auth?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0)

Comment: @Greg_Fenton  Yes i can see email logged in

Comment: @Greg_Fenton i saw this too **D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( rZtHrQVjNMnBKtYcKDQ2 )**                              i saw the auth id then it means the user is logged at that time. **i want to know how to get that to any of my veriable**

Answer (score 0):

In `handleFacebookAccessToken()`

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       
        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "email" + user.getEmail());
                    //--------------Here is the UID
                    Log.i(TAG, "uid" + user.getUid());
                }

         }
```